I can't connect a QPushButton to a function when clicked
I'm new to QtDesigner and I've been looking at similar questions all day, but just can't figure out what is the problem. I was just trying to test if I could make a function work just by clicking a button on my QApplication. The QPushButton object that I'm trying to work with is located in the class below.
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'loginPage.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.8.0
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_LOGINPAGE_H
#define UI_LOGINPAGE_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QLineEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_loginPageClass
{
public:
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QLabel *label;
    QLabel *label_2;
    QLineEdit *usernameLineEdit;
    QLabel *label_3;
    QLineEdit *passwordLineEdit;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer;
    QPushButton *loginPushButton;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer_2;
    QLabel *statusLabel;

    void setupUi(QWidget *loginPageClass)
    {
        if (loginPageClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            loginPageClass->setObjectName("loginPageClass");
        loginPageClass->resize(328, 236);
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(loginPageClass);
        gridLayout->setSpacing(6);
        gridLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        gridLayout->setObjectName("gridLayout");
        verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        verticalLayout->setSpacing(6);
        verticalLayout->setObjectName("verticalLayout");
        label = new QLabel(loginPageClass);
        label->setObjectName("label");
        QFont font;
        font.setFamilies({QString::fromUtf8("Gill Sans MT")});
        font.setPointSize(25);
        font.setBold(false);
        label->setFont(font);
        label->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"));
        label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignCenter);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(label);

        label_2 = new QLabel(loginPageClass);
        label_2->setObjectName("label_2");
        QFont font1;
        font1.setFamilies({QString::fromUtf8("Gill Sans MT")});
        font1.setPointSize(15);
        font1.setBold(false);
        label_2->setFont(font1);
        label_2->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"));
        label_2->setAlignment(Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignCenter);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(label_2);

        usernameLineEdit = new QLineEdit(loginPageClass);
        usernameLineEdit->setObjectName("usernameLineEdit");
        usernameLineEdit->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8(""));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(usernameLineEdit);

        label_3 = new QLabel(loginPageClass);
        label_3->setObjectName("label_3");
        label_3->setFont(font1);
        label_3->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"));
        label_3->setAlignment(Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignCenter);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(label_3);

        passwordLineEdit = new QLineEdit(loginPageClass);
        passwordLineEdit->setObjectName("passwordLineEdit");
        passwordLineEdit->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8(""));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(passwordLineEdit);

        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        horizontalLayout->setSpacing(6);
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName("horizontalLayout");
        horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Policy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Policy::Minimum);

        horizontalLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer);

        loginPushButton = new QPushButton(loginPageClass);
        loginPushButton->setObjectName("loginPushButton");
        loginPushButton->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8(""));

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(loginPushButton);

        horizontalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Policy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Policy::Minimum);

        horizontalLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer_2);


        verticalLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout);

        statusLabel = new QLabel(loginPageClass);
        statusLabel->setObjectName("statusLabel");
        QFont font2;
        font2.setFamilies({QString::fromUtf8("Gill Sans MT")});
        font2.setPointSize(12);
        font2.setBold(false);
        statusLabel->setFont(font2);
        statusLabel->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"));
        statusLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignCenter);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(statusLabel);


        gridLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1);


        retranslateUi(loginPageClass);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(loginPageClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *loginPageClass)
    {
        loginPageClass->setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication::translate("loginPageClass", "loginPage", nullptr));
        label->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("loginPageClass", "BANKALAR PORTAL'I", nullptr));
        label_2->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("loginPageClass", "Kullan\304\261c\304\261 Ad\304\261:", nullptr));
        label_3->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("loginPageClass", "\305\236ifre:", nullptr));
        loginPushButton->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("loginPageClass", "Giri\305\237 Yap", nullptr));
        statusLabel->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("loginPageClass", "", nullptr));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class loginPageClass: public Ui_loginPageClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_LOGINPAGE_H


I want to run a random function I made when the loginPushButton in Ui_loginPageClass is clicked. To do this, I implemented the main() function below.
#include <iostream>
#include "bankPage.h"
#include "depositApproval.h"
#include "depositPage.h"
#include "loginPage.h"
#include "transferApproval.h"
#include "transferPage.h"
#include "withdrawApproval.h"
#include "withdrawPage.h"
#include "operationsClass.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QObject>

void prntsmth(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    bankPage bankPageWindow;
    depositApproval depositApprovalWindow;
    depositPage depositPageWindow;
    loginPage loginPageWindow;
    transferApproval transferApprovalWindow;
    transferPage transferPageWindow;
    withdrawApproval withdrawApprovalWindow;
    withdrawPage withdrawPageWindow;
    
    operationsClass* operations = new operationsClass;
    //Ui_loginPageClass loginPageUI;
    Ui_loginPageClass* loginPageUI = new Ui_loginPageClass;
    //loginPageUI->setupUi(this);
    //Ui_loginPageClass loginPageUI;

    //loginPageUI->passwordLineEdit->setText("naber");
    //loginPageUI->usernameLineEdit->setText("naber");
    //std::cout << loginPageUI->loginPushButton;
    //QObject::connect(loginPageUI->loginPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), loginPageUI->passwordLineEdit, SLOT(prntsmth()));
    QWidget::connect(loginPageUI->loginPushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, prntsmth);

    loginPageWindow.show();

    

    return a.exec();
}


After the operationsClass pointer initialization, I tried pretty much everything I could find online. In some forums it said that I'm getting a dangling pointer error or something? But I don't know how to fix it. I get the following error when I run this solution.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9E1056D9B (Qt6Cored.dll) in TCP_Banking_Client_QtApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
I tried pretty much every commented line in main.cpp file.

I'm sure you could come up with a much shorter [mre] for that. To connect something to a signal you can just use a lambda as the minimal thing.

Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF This likely means the object no longer exists or never was constructed. I had the same error this week from accessing a vector of objects with an off by 1 error ( I tried to access vec[3] of a vector of 3 elements). To my defense I wrote the code at 2:00 AM and was sleepy..

// loginPageUI->setupUi(this); my guts tell me this commented line is supposed to create the object that is causing the segfault for not being there (hence you dereferenced a nullptr)

Now reviewing your code, your bug appears to be setupUi() was never called for the loginPageUI. I am unsure why you are constructing your widget in this unusual way. Normally you have a QWidget class which either inherits from the Ui or uses composition with the Ui.

Ahmed AEK commented to use loginPageUI->setupUi(this) but since that line is in the main() function, the compiler doesn't let me use "this" keyword.

As I was typing in my last comment you are using this Ui in a very unusual way.

See the CalculatorForm class in the example here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

How can I use it the normal way. I just want to run a function by QPushButton button click.

it will likely be loginPageUI->setupUi(some_window); where some_window could be a simple QWindow

@AhmedAEK I suppose you meant QWidget.

I solved the problem. I was trying to access the wrong header file or something. Dumb mistake.

@EmirhanAk That makes your post as non reproducible, and therefore off topic on StackOverflow, as previously suspected. I'd suggest you to delete it on your own, as it's been marked as such to begin with.
